# Why is the speed of light constant in all inertial frames?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

I know this is a physical principle and cannot be derived at from other physical laws. But how can it be arrived at? What observations or what train of thoughts leads to this conclusion?

e.g. the Newton's second law of motion is also a physical principle and cannot be derived. But from observations like 'a body moving at constant velocity on a frictionless surface doesn't tend to stop' and many others, it is understandable to arrive  at the Newton's laws.
What observations or thought process lead Einstein to this postulate?

Comment: If you're asking about how Einstein arrived at his postulates then that really a question for the [history of science SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For example [The motivation for relativity theory](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/622/the-motivation-for-relativity-theory)

Comment: Maxwell's equations output a single value for the speed of light; independent of the reference frame.